# Multiple Counts that are grouped, from multiple tables, with a join thrown in

Tags: sql, oracle, join, group-by

I have two tables that hold image paths. The counts of approved images should equal the count of published images but I have evidence that they do not. One table has to have a join to group by the same criteria as the other table. I only want to return rows where the two counts don't match up. I've included the two queries I have that would return the data individually. Even if I tried to use Excel as a crutch, the amount of rows this query would return is in the millions.

Query 1

```
select product_id, count(*)
from published p
join published_set ps on ps.id = p.media_set_id
group by ps.product_id
```

Query 2

```
select product_id, count(*)
from media
where status in 'APPROVED'
group by pro_sku
```

I did use Excel to pull one category of products that I suspected was the worst and got 8,000 mismatches out of 12,000 products. I want to compare this to other areas of the website, which I believe have little to no mismatches. My suspicion is a system is inserting data into the table incorrectly in a specific category.

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: I want to use a query to analyze the entirety of our product catalog. How do I marry up these two separate queries into one query? If I query these one at a time by category I'd be running over 100,000 queries.

Answer (score 0):

Your question does leave a little to be clarified. For example, when you say 8,000 mismatches, how are you determining that there are 8,000 mismatches? Is this just the difference in the totals from the grouping? Also, is your concern that there are published images that have not been approved, or the other way around?

Listing the columns of the tables may help here, as I don't know what information you need to understand the issue at hand.

Edit: Provided the following query that lists the counts and those product_id's where the count is different. Nothing too hard here. Let me know if this doesn't satisfy what you are after. You just need to join what you already had really, and then selecting those rows where the counts are not equal.

```
select Published.product_id,Published_Count,Media_Count
from (
    select product_id, count(*) as Published_Count
    from published p
    join published_set ps on ps.id = p.media_set_id
    group by ps.product_id
) Published

join (
    select product_id,count(*) as Media_Count
    from media
    where [status] = 'APPROVED'
    group by product_id
) Media
on Published.product_id = Media.product_id
where Published_Count <> Media_Count
```

Comment: I pulled the counts in both tables for one specific category and it had roughly 12,000 products in it. I used Excel to compare the counts of the images by product id between the two tables e.g. this table has three images for product #12 but the other table has five images for product #12. In that category 8,000 products had a mismatch in images between the two tables.

Comment: I thought posting the queries would give the relevant columns. But if you think it would help, here is the info.

Media- ID PRODUCT_ID, TYPE, VENDOR_ID, STATUS, Modified_Date, Modified_By, assigned_date, assigned_to

Published_Set - ID, Product_id, Name

Published - ID, Media_set_id, Name, Position, server_path, width, height

Comment: I would like my output to look something like this...

PRODUCT_ID, MEDIA_COUNT, PUBLISHED_COUNT;
90012578,                 2,                             8,
85413256,                1,                             3,
25698741,                 3,                            1,